# Creating d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, webstorm

I have a csv file that contains the top songs on Spotify from 2010-2019. The attributes of each song have things like genre, artist, year, popularity, bpm, etc. I wanted to create a bar graph that has the year on the x-axis, popularity on the y-axis, and then each genre represents a different color bar on the chart. I have attached the csv file I am using, any help would be appreciated.

link to csv:
https://github.com/moonpieluvincutie/Spotify

Comment: Use D3 stacked bar chart: http://bl.ocks.org/mstanaland/6100713

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you are looking for stacked bars but if not, un-stacked would be the easier approach. Using this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208) as a base, we need to first transform the data to represent the configuration you described in your post. Essentially we need to group by `year`, `genre` and transform it in a way that is suitable for stacking. For example something like this...

```js
const data = [
  { month: new Date(2015, 0, 1), apples: 3840, bananas: 1920, cherries: 960, dates: 400 },
];
```

or in the case of your data something like this...

```js
const data = [
  { year: 2015, genre1: popularity1, genre2: popularity1, ...rest },
];
```

Fortunately `d3` offers a plethora of [`transformations`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v2.12.1/README.md#transformations) for us to use.

> Note: I am using d3 v6 not v4 (like the example) in the following code, the API is slightly different but essentially the same concepts.

I created the following working snippet for you to review. I used [`d3.rollups`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v2.12.1/README.md#rollups) to group the data in the way described above. I would advise you to log each transform to see what the new structure looks like. I took the [`d3.mean`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/v2.12.1/README.md#mean) of the popularity if there was more than 1 song per genre per year. Once you have the structure in the shape defined above, we pass that to [`d3.stack`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v2.1.0/README.md#stack) to format the data with correct `y0` and `y1` values for each series (aka group or genre).

Finally, by adding the stacked dataset to the rendering logic from the base example with a few tweaks, you get something like this below. Sorry, it's a bit unpolished but this should give you a good start point to iterate from.

[image: example preview]

```js
const svg = d3.select("svg"),
  margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = +svg.attr("width") - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


// Set x, y and colors
const x = d3.scaleBand()
  .rangeRound([10, width - 10])
  .padding(0.2)

const y = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([height, 0]);

const z = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePaired);

d3.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/moonpieluvincutie/Spotify/main/top10s%20(version%201).xlsb.csv', (d) => ({
  year: +d.year,
  pop: d.pop,
  genre: d['top genre'],
})).then((data) => {
  // Transform the data into groups by genre and year 
  const groupedDataset = d3.rollups(data, v => d3.mean(v, d => d.pop), d => d.year, d => d.genre)
  const flattenedDataset = groupedDataset.map(([year, values]) => {
    return {
      year,
      ...values.reduce((acc, [genre, pop]) => {
        acc[genre] = pop;
        return acc;
      }, {}),
    }
  });
    
  const genres = d3.rollups(data, () => null, d => d.genre).map(([genre]) => genre);
  
  // Stack grouped data
  const dataset = d3.stack()
    .keys(genres)
    .value((d, key) => d[key] ?? 0)
    .order(d3.stackOrderNone)
    .offset(d3.stackOffsetNone)
    (flattenedDataset)
  
  // Assign x, y and z (aka genre group) domains
  x.domain(groupedDataset.map(([year]) => year));  
  y.domain([0, d3.max(
    dataset, (d) => { 
      return d3.max(d, ([y]) => y)
    }
  )]).nice();
  z.domain(genres);
  
  const yAxis = d3.axisLeft()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
    .tickFormat( (d) => { return d } );

  const xAxis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(x)
  
  g.append("g")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(dataset)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", (d) => z(d.key))
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data((d) =>  d)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("x", (d) => x(+d.data.year))
      .attr("y", (d) => y(d[1]))
      .attr("height", (d) => y(d[0]) - y(d[1]))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth());

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  g.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("x", 2)
      .attr("y", y(y.ticks().pop()) + 0.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("font-weight", "bold")
      .attr("text-anchor", "start")
      .text("Popularity");

  const legend = g.append("g")
      .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
      .attr("font-size", 10)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(genres.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("transform", (d, i) => "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")");

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 19)
      .attr("width", 19)
      .attr("height", 19)
      .attr("fill", z);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9.5)
      .attr("dy", "0.32em")
      .text((d) => d);
})
```

```css
.axis .domain {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- chart appended to svg in javaScript -->
  <svg width="960" height="500"></svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The way you explained each step was very helpful in understanding the process. I am just now learning d3 and this was extremely useful, I appreciate it.

Comment: Just to clarify, in the example you gave for how I need to group my data by year and genre. I will write out year, genre, and the score of popularity for each song title?

Comment: I am not sure if you receive notifications when I comment or if I have to tag you, so I'm doing both. My apologizes. @Nickofthyme

Comment: No worries, yes you are notified of comments on posts. Not sure what you are asking but It really depends on how you want to visualize the data. You could group all songs by genre then by year and take the average as I did in the example, then list all the songs in a tooltip. Or you could render all songs as individual bars that are colored by genre. If I were you I would look at other examples on https://observablehq.com/@d3 and see how others display data that may be similar in nature, to yours. Once you know how you want it to look then you can understand the data manipulation you'll need.